# Disable Text_Change event VBA

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Dears,

Is there a way to disable Textbox_change event?I try

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

but it does not works.

```
    If .txtHomeNumber.Value <> "" Then
        If IsNumeric(txtHomeNumber.Value) Then
            .txtHomeNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .txtMobileNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            .txtParentsNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        Else: MsgBox "Please enter a valid Home Number in Contact Details section.", vbExclamation, "Contact Details"
            Application.EnableEvents = False
                .txtHomeNumber.Value = Left(.txtHomeNumber.Value, Len(.txtHomeNumber.Value) - 1)
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Add a module level boolean variable and check it as the first line in the event - `If bEnabled Then.... <do stuff> Else <don't do stuff> End If`.

Comment: Or don't use the change-event as it gets triggered every change, use a afterupdate or exit event

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook i m new in Userform use.could you please provide an example?thanks a lot for the quick respond.

Comment: What are the conditions when you don't want the event to fire - I take it you want the event to fire sometimes?

Answer (score 0):

This code uses a `TextBox` and `CommandButton` on a `Userform`.
I've just added the button so you can changed between *enabled* and *disabled*.

```
Option Explicit

Private bEnabled As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Starts as FALSE so change to TRUE when form first opens.
    bEnabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

    If bEnabled Then
        MsgBox "Enabled"
'        If .txtHomeNumber.Value <> "" Then
'            If IsNumeric(txtHomeNumber.Value) Then
'                .txtHomeNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'                .txtMobileNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'                .txtParentsNumber.BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'            Else: MsgBox "Please enter a valid Home Number in Contact Details section.", vbExclamation, "Contact Details"
'                Application.EnableEvents = False
'                    .txtHomeNumber.Value = Left(.txtHomeNumber.Value, Len(.txtHomeNumber.Value) - 1)
'                Application.EnableEvents = True
'                Exit Sub
'            End If
'        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    bEnabled = Not bEnabled
End Sub
```

Looking at your code - are you sure you don't want to have it in the `AfterUpdate` event?

Answer (score 0):

I usually define my own boolean this looks like this:

```
Public DisableEvents As Boolean

Private Sub SomeObject_Change()
    If Not DisableEvents Then
        DisableEvents = True
            ' do_stuff
        DisableEvents = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This works and prevent the infinite loop you otherwise create.