# How do I disable the change events

Tags: vba, events, userform

Currently I have several worksheets and plenty of values that are input or equal something. However with so many worksheets "talking" to each other, this appears to be causing issues. this occurs directly when a field is changed or button is pushed as I expect it to...
but  it also happens indirectly when i'm capturing the data and writing it back to the userform with something like Form.textbox.value = range("A1") triggering the change event for the textbox.

Can someone comment if this is a code structure issue? Is there a best practice for what pieces of code should be separated?

I tried the application.enableevents = False but this does not seem to work with the user form the way i would expect. I found the link below and it seems to describe my issue to a tee but I'm not understanding what they mean by putting a public value in the "userform's module" the rest of disabling it and reenabling it makes sense

Link:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SuppressChangeInForms.htm

Can someone dumb this down for me or give a better option? Is this common?

Thanks,

[Code after adding the public variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EdQw.png)

[Module where the information causes change event to trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfhUv.png)

Comment: The link you posted is pretty straightforward code - which part is giving you problems?  Do you have any code to share?  The userform's "module" is where the code for your form is - a public/global variable would be placed at the top of the module before any Sub/Function code.  E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53260718/disable-text-change-event-vba

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents` controls Excel's event-firing. As you're finding out, a UserForm control's events have nothing to do with Excel's object model. "putting a public value in the "userform's module" - press F7 when you're in the form designer, and you'll be in the "userform's module", aka the form's *code-behind*. When you're in the form's code-behind, Shift+F7 opens the designer. The snippet that starts with `Public EnableEvents As Boolean` is the code you want to have in the form's module, and the `ListBox1_Change` snippet shows how to check the flag and bail out (`Exit Sub`).

Comment: Thank you both for looking at this so far I've learned that the Shift F7 can get me to the code of the user form without having to scroll through or run using stop break so thank you for that.

As I'm learning i hear don't use public variables because they slow your code down so I've not spent much time learning how to do them properly. While this seems very remedial its me not having experience with this (self taught).
Putting the Boolean above the UF Initialize() separates it under the previous end sub with a line and putting it under the Userform Initialize seems to generate the error

Comment: Added two images to help. Red arrow point  to where the code trigger the change events in the module - Tim

Other image is me not getting the syntax or something in correctly

Comment: The public variable goes right at the top of the module, right under `Option Explicit` and outside of any Sub or Function.